# How to add customized icon to Ubuntu top menu bar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, icons

I want to create an icon in top menu bar which lists the USB devices attached to the system. How can I add an icon to the top menubar? Where are the config files for that? I have gone through `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop`, but how to make it visible on top menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Unity, I don't think it's customizable. Maybe you can customize the top menu by installing Ubuntu Tweak (`sudo apt install ubuntu-tweak`) or install Unity Tweak or something like that.

However, if you install Gnome 2 (`sudo apt install gnome`, reboot and login to the "Gnome Flashback/Fallback" option) you can customize the top menu by dragging the icon or the `*.desktop` file to it.

Hoping for the best,

Bajiru